# Get x coordinates in a new field in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

In desktop you can do that by: `calculate geometry` and then select `X_Coordinate_of_centroid`. How to do this in ArcPy?

Tried:

```
arcpy.AddField_management("f1.shp","X_Coord","DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("f1.shp","X_Coord") #how to make this work?
```

It needs also the expression parameter.